# What is Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby

I am novice about ruby and getting lot of confusing what is ruby and where it used.
I am requesting a small description about ruby. How to get started with ruby.

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your title asks a question, which is significantly different from the one in your question's body, so I'll answer both separately.

First the one in the body:

> What is ruby and where it used

Ruby is a dynamic, object oriented programming language. It is a general purpose language, but most often used for scripting (as a replacement for perl or shell scripts) and web programming.

> How to get started with ruby.

[ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org) has a list of free tutorials and books for learning ruby.

Now the question in the title:

> What is Ruby on Rails?

Ruby on Rails is a web framework for ruby. It is used for programming web applications using the MVC paradigm.

Comment: Thank You Seep2k ,,, my confusion is cleared now...

Answer (score 4):

You can simply start with Ruby in your browser: http://tryruby.org/

Answer (score 1):

> How to get started with ruby.

Don't get started with it. It's syntax is awkward - I think the girlfriend of the guy who made ruby was a perl programmer.

---

Now, for a more serious answer: Ruby is a scripting language like Python, PERL, etc.
To quote [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29):

> Ruby is a dynamic, reflective, general purpose object-oriented programming language that combines syntax inspired by Perl with Smalltalk-like features

I'd suggest you to read the article about ruby as it explains a lot about its philosophy etc.

[Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) is a web development framework for ruby. Have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html for a quick overview about it.

Comment: You must be a Python programmer.

Comment: Believe it or not, Matz is a fan of Perl and Python. He just wanted something even better. @Mark: It's worse than that. He does PHP three times as much as Python!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the information found here:

http://rubyonrails.org/

Past that, I would setup a Linux server and start experimenting with it! That's the best way to learn anything. If you don't know much about Linux, you could run it on Windows.

-Brian J. Stinar-